# Overriding keyDown in NSWindowController with NSTableView | responding to spacebar

Tags: macos, nstableview, nswindowcontroller, nsevent

So I have a `NSTableView` inside `NSWindowController`. When I press spacebar it goes through `NSResponder` and stops on `NSWindow` which calls `performClick:` on the `NSTableView` (`NSControl`)
All other key events are handled in `NSWindowController`. How do I catch a spacebar event?

```
//NSWindowController
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    if ([[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] isEqual:@" "]) {
        [self togglePreviewPanel:self];
    } else {
        [super keyDown:event];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with this


 - (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        if ([event KeyCode]==48) {
            [self togglePreviewPanel:self];
        } else {
            [super keyDown:event];
        }
    }
```

//If KeyDown event doesn't work try with 'keyUp' event.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. How is your solution different to mine? I wanted to catch spacebar in the NSWindowController. Have you tried your code? Not much comment why this should work.

Comment: 1. "I feel" is not very scientific or backed with a knowledge or a documentation. BTW it's the same in underlying framework function. 2. Technically you are right about the keyUp in NSWindowController. However your technical writing needs to improve a lot. PS: "put that method in your implementation" is very vague and doesn't answer question put it into NSWindowController (subclass).